# Re Increment the Primary Column after deletion of the record in table in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-update, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

i want to do this one to my child table.

check the primary key.It does not contains Identity Specification.

when inserting data my table should be like this when i delete a record it should be shown below.

how can i do this after deleting the record i want to update the next rows ....,and the result should like below

how can i do this any ideas..., please this is important for me...,

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql delete,autoincrement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643938/mysql-delete-autoincrement) Don't do this! Have a look at the answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.table 
    SET splr_Slno=splr_Slno-1 
WHERE 
splr_Slno> @splr_Slno AND splr_Id= @Splr_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Trigger, that refreshes your data after the delete query runs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TableDeleted]
    ON [dbo].[Table]
    AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN

   BEGIN TRAN X
       UPDATE Table SET Column1 WHERE...
   COMMIT TRAN X
END
```

Comment: Please don't support this. Have a look here, why this is not a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643938/mysql-delete-autoincrement

Comment: His question is valid.  The OP doesn't have autoincrement turned on. He has a compound primary key, where he wants to reorder one of the columns.