# Why mysql autoincrement increments the last used id rather then the last existing id

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql, and am looking at a strange behavior. 
Scenario :
I have a table having `table_id` as `primary key`, which is set to `auto-increment`.

```
table_id  more_columns
1         some value
2          others
```

Now if i delete row 2, and insert one more row, the table_id becomes 3 (Expected is 2)

```
table_id  more_columns
    1         some value
    3          recent
```

Why is it so? Here I am loosing some ids (I know they are not important). Please put some lights on this behavior

Comment: mysql internally stores the last autoincremented id per column. if you delete a row (might be the first or a row inbetween) it will not update that internal value

Comment: Yes i agree, but i wanted to know what is the logic behind this

Comment: Logic behind this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643938/mysql-delete-autoincrement

Comment: thanks i got the answer. Possible duplicate. did not came up when i googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto_increment value is a counter stored internally for each table. The counter is only increased, never decreased. 
Every syntactically correct INSERT statement fired against the table increments this counter, even when it is rolled back and also when you define an insert value for the primary key.

Comment: is there a way to get this internally stored counter?

Comment: @techG: You can get next assignable counter value from `AUTO_INCREMENT` column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Answer (score 1):

In auto-increment field If a row is deleted, the `auto_increment` column of that row will not be re-assigned.

Please see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more information.

For reasons why auto-increment doesn't use deleted values you can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644089/1551233)(mentioned in comments by @AaronBlenkush).

Comment: yes, but i am expecting some information on the logic behind this

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL `auto_increment` column maintains a number internally, and will always increment it, even after deletions.  If you need to fill in an empty space, you have to handle it yourself in PHP, rather than use the `auto_increment` keyword in the table definition.

Rolling back to fill in empty row ids can cause all sorts of difficulty if you have foreign key relationships to maintain, and it really isn't advised.

The `auto_increment` can be reset using a SQL statement, but this is not advised because it will cause duplicate key errors.

```
-- Doing this will cause problems!
ALTER table AUTO_INCREMENT=12345;
```

**EDIT**
To enforce your foreign key relationships as described in the comments, you should add to your table definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY (friendid) REFERENCES registration_table (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Fill in the correct table and column names.  Now, when a user is deleted from the registration, their friend association is nulled.  If you need to reassociate with a different user, that has to be handled with PHP.  `mysql_insert_id()` is no longer helpful.

If you need to find the highest numbered id still in the database after deletion to associate with friends, use the following.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM registration_table;
```

After delete write this query

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: if i have foreign key relation , i will not be able to delete